# Friend a template function and avoid virtual functions/abstract bases

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I want to befriend a function template and want to restrict the template type as much as possible.

Below is a snippet from a larger hierarchy such that `T` in `template <class T> void Play(T&);` can be of the form `T`, or `T<U>`. In case of `T<U>`, which means T is a class template, I would like to befriend the function specialized for `T<U>`.

The expected behavior for the snippet below is successful  compilation/linking/execution without producing the output `This should not be printed`.

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Genre { Rock = 111, Pop = 999 };

/* this is the global interface: */
template <class T> void Play(T&);

template <Genre genre> class Song {
    /* befriend own player */
    template <class T> friend void Play(Song<genre>&);
private:
    int v = int(genre);
};

/* desired function resolution: */
template <Genre genre> void Play(Song<genre>& d)
{ 
    std::cout << "Genre: " << d.v << std::endl; 
}

template <class T> void Play(T& d)
{
    std::cout << "This should not be printed" << std::endl;
}

/* these two functions are not desired but I tried... */
template<> inline void Play(Song<Genre::Pop>& d)
{ Play<Genre::Pop>(d); }

template<> inline void Play(Song<Genre::Rock>& d)
{ Play<Genre::Rock>(d); }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Song<Genre::Pop> s;
    Song<Genre::Rock> p;
    Play<decltype(s)>(s);  
    Play(s);
    Play(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you make your `Play` functions for specialization  recursive? What was your original intention?

Comment: No absolutely not what you call recursive is me trying to call the desired function.

Comment: Do you really need that `Play<decltype(s)>(s);` expression to call the genre overload?

Comment: @TartanLlama, yes, but without `decltype`. The `Play` function is called like this: `Play<T>(Tinstance)` from another function template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues here that I could identify: your `friend` declaration is picking up the wrong function and your two "not desired" functions recursively call themselves.

To fix the first, we need to tell the compiler that the `Play` function is a template before it starts looking at the `Song` class:

```
/* this is the global interface: */
//need to forward declare the Song template class
template <Genre genre> class Song;

//forward declare the version of Play templated on Genre
template <Genre genre> 
void Play(Song<genre>&);

//keep the version you had originally
template <typename T>
void Play(T&);

template <Genre genre> class Song {
    /* befriend own player */
    //now picks up the correct function
    friend void Play <> (Song<genre>&);
private:
    int v = int(genre);
};
```

For your forwarding functions, we need to make them full specializations of the `template <typename T> Play(T&>` version:

```
template <> 
void Play<Song<Genre::Pop>> (Song<Genre::Pop>& d)
{ Play(d); }

template <> 
void Play<Song<Genre::Rock>> (Song<Genre::Rock>& d)
{ Play(d); }
```

An alternative is to make a type trait checking if you have passed in a `Song`, then enable/disable the function with SFINAE:

```
template <class T>
struct is_song : std::false_type {};

template <Genre genre>
struct is_song<Song<genre>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_song<T>::value>* = nullptr> 
void Play (T& d)
{ Play(d); }

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!is_song<T>::value>* = nullptr>
void Play(T& d)
{
    std::cout << "This should not be printed" << std::endl;
}
```

Now everything works! [Demo](https://ideone.com/xdJtCV)

Comment: Thanks a lot, is it not possible to write a single forwarding function?

Comment: What you would want for a single forwarding function is something like `template <Genre g> 
void Play<Song<g>> (Song<g>& d)
{ Play(d); }`. Unfortunately you can't partially specialize functions. As I mentioned, you could do it if `Play` was a functor instead of a function.

Comment: @perreal actually I came up with a way to have a single forwarding function. I don't know how nicely it'll fit in with your real code, but it works for the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Genre : int { Rock = 111, Pop = 999 };

template<Genre genre> class Song;

/* this is the global interface: */
template <Genre genre> void Play(Song<genre>&);

template <Genre genre>
class Song
{
   /* befriend own player */
   friend void Play<>(Song<genre>&);

   private:
      int v = int(genre);
};

/* desired function resolution: */
template <Genre genre>
void Play(Song<genre>& d)
{
   std::cout << "Genre: " << d.v << std::endl;
}

/* non-desired function */
template <class T> 
void Play(T& d)
{
   std::cout << "This should not be printed" << d.v << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    Song<Genre::Pop> s;
    Song<Genre::Rock> p;
    //Play<decltype(s)>(s); // <--- will not compile: calls the 'non-desired' function
                            // <--- which is not friend of Song<Genre::Pop>
                            // <--- and compilation fails as the function tries to access the private member v
    Play(s);
    Play(p);
    //Play<Genre::Rock>(s);   // <--- will also not compile
    return 0;
}
```

Here `Play` is only `friend` of `Song`s of the 'specific' `genre`.